# Как исправить невозможность удалить запись в вордпрессе?

Tags: wordpress

Есть произвольный тип записи со своими настройками доступа 'capabilities'. Администратор не может удалить такой пост. Редактировать, сделать черновиком может.

```
function register_post_types(){
    register_post_type('event', array(
        'label'  => null,
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => 'События', // основное название для типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Событие', // название для одной записи этого типа
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить ', // для добавления новой записи
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление ', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование ', // для редактирования типа записи
            'new_item'           => 'Новое ', // текст новой записи
            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть ', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
            'search_items'       => 'Искать ', // для поиска по этим типам записи
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
            'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
            'menu_name'          => 'События', // название меню
        ),
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
        'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
        'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
        'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // по умолчанию значение show_in_menu
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
        'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
        'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
        'menu_position'       => null,
        'menu_icon'           => null, 
        'capability_type'   => array('event','events'),
        'capabilities' => array(
          'edit_post'          => 'edit_event',
          'edit_posts'         => 'edit_events',          
          'read_post'          => 'read_event', 
          'delete_post'        => 'delete_event',
          'delete_posts'       => 'delete_events',
          'delete_private_posts'       => 'delete_private_events',
          'delete_published_posts'       => 'delete_published_events',   
          'delete_others_posts'       => 'delete_others_events',          
          'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_others_events', 
          'publish_posts'      => 'publish_events',       
          'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_events', 
          'create_posts'       => 'edit_events',
            ),          
        'map_meta_cap'      => false, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'supports'            => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields','comments','page-attributes'),
        'taxonomies'          => array('rub', 'ob'),
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
    ) );
}
```

Плагин управления ролями видит такие права:

[image: Плагин управления ролями видит такие права]

Ссылки "удалить" нет, если выбрать списком удалить, то ошибка "Извините, вам не разрешено перемещать этот элемент в корзину."

Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'map_meta_cap'      => false, //поставить true
```

заменить на "true", я пробовал это на другом сайте и там с такой настройкой кто-то нежелательный получал права доступа к определенному типу записи.

Но в данном случае, с двумя ролями на сайте это помогло.